# Getting error while starting spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and I have created new Startup project from https://start.spring.io/ and added few dependencies like WEB,JPA & Devtools. I have used Oracle Database so I have updated my application.properties with below configuration.
I am getting Logon denied exception but when I am using same datasource in hibernate my application runs successfully.

```
application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.datasource.data-username=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.data-password=xxxxxx
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

---

```
Error Log
2018-02-10 13:27:45.943  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.r.S.SpringRestServiceApplication     : Starting SpringRestServiceApplication on DESKTOP-LJPNF78 with PID 12404 (C:\SpringBoot\SpringRestService\target\classes started by AbhishekChouhan in C:\SpringBoot\SpringRestService)
2018-02-10 13:27:45.945  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.r.S.SpringRestServiceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-10 13:27:46.038  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2ef3efe: startup date [Sat Feb 10 13:27:46 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-10 13:27:48.426  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type 

[org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d4f954a5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-10 13:27:49.354  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-10 13:27:49.374  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-10 13:27:49.374  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-02-10 13:27:49.394  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven\bin;C:\Users\AbhishekChouhan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\AbhishekChouhan\Desktop;;.]
2018-02-10 13:27:49.844  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-10 13:27:49.844  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3810 ms
2018-02-10 13:27:50.095  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-02-10 13:27:50.102  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-10 13:27:50.103  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-10 13:27:50.103  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-10 13:27:50.103  INFO 12404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-10 13:27:50.646  INFO 12404 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-02-10 13:27:50.654  WARN 12404 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2018-02-10 13:27:52.128 ERROR 12404 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:375) ~[HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:204) ~[HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:459) [HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:533) [HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:114) [HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:107) [HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:168) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:109) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d01714.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d01714$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1954e591.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3d01714.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at com.spring.restservice.SpringRestService.SpringRestServiceApplication.main(SpringRestServiceApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

2018-02-10 13:27:52.137  WARN 12404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
```

Comment: please show your pom.xml file??

Comment: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver include this line last then check

Comment: thanks for your reply but I found the issue. The issue is in application.properties I have used spring.datasource.data-username=xxxxxx which is wrong actually it should be spring.datasource.username=xxxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in application.properties I have used spring.datasource.data-username=xxxxxx which is wrong actually it should be spring.datasource.username=xxxxxx

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should use the following value for Oracle:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I found this based on the info in this discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/qpGMuMituqY

Open your JAR's /META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file and copy the string found there.

Answer (score 1):

You change your spring datasource property in the following **sequence** declaration:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.data-username=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.data-password=xxxxxx
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

You often won’t need to specify the driver-class-name since Spring boot can deduce it for most databases from the url.

**Note:**

For a pooling DataSource to be created we need to be able to verify that a valid Driver class is available, so we check for that before doing anything. I.e. if you set spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver then that class has to be loadable.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't install the right driver:

```
Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found
```

For a MySQL db there's a dependecy you have to add, so there has to be one for Oracle, too. Maybe this site helps: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution... Do you have something holding the server port open?  I had to kill Java processes that did not shut down properly.